# Seq doesn't capture ASP.NET Core 6 Web API logs inside of docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core-webapi, sequence, serilog, gelf

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API application, which is running as Docker Container, and the app uses Serilog and Seq. I experienced that Seq doesn't capture my app's logs. I read several articles, and I found a Gelf, so I installed seq-input-gelf, and run it as a container which is using UDP port, but the logs are showing nothing, only this message always logs:

> "Collected GELF server metrics"

How to configure Seq to see logs from my app?

`appsettings.json`:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Exceptions", "Serilog", "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.Seq" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Seq",
        "Args": {
          "serverUrl": "http://localhost:5341",
          "apiKey": "none",
          "restrictedMinimumLevel": "Verbose",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Containers:
[image: Containers]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I got this message from the Containers Logs Tab:
Exception while emitting periodic batch from Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.PeriodicBatchingSink: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address (localhost:12201)
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address